# SharePoint looping on the same page? It's always HTTP 301 response

Tags: sharepoint, http-status-code-301

I don't know what happened on the SharePoint website. When I go to the page, it will always loop on the same page. For example, you go to www.example.com, then the www.example.com redirects itself to www.example.com and so on until the browser Firefox throws an error:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Anyone experiencing like this one?

Comment: correction on this -> i don't want happen., 

this is the correct -> i don't know want happen

Comment: My server is Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Comment: Have you tired other browsers?

Comment: Is it occurring on every sharepoint page?

Comment: i've tried on firefox and chrome and the outcome is the same, occurring on every sarepoint page? no. only on specific pages.